# How to get Swagger API definition for the WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 API Manager Product, which seems free (open source), I am refereeing to https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Quick+Start+Guide and specifically refereeing to "**Adding interactive documentation using Swagger**" Swagger API definition screen, but they have not given Swagger API definition itself. I am not able to developed anything outoff it later.

Could anyone please provide "Swagger API definition"? Please help..
This is only half Swagger API definition. I need full sample ..

[image]

Comment: Swagger API definition for which API? Please provide some more details regarding what you want to achive.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need to same Swagger API definition shown in screen shot first. However you can provide me all API definitions if you've handy with you..Thank you.. Neha
Do you know how we can create Proxy for the Restful (Spring MVC) web service in WSO2 API manager ?

Answer (score 1):

we can get Swagger API definition from clicking Edit Source(Add-->Design new API --> start creating-->click Edit Source button) 
In API Manager 1.7.0 or previous versions, we are creating the Swagger definition at the API creation time only. So if some one add more API resources by editing APIs, those will not get reflected in the Swagger JSON.